# How many accessories can a mouse equip in Mice and Mystics

Tags: mice-and-mystics

The accessory cards do not show a usage slot (head, body, paws).  Does that mean there is no limit to how many a single mouse can equip?  Or are they limited to one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This BGG thread](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/911840/accessory-cards) contains confirmation from the game's designer that you can equip as many accessories at once as you want.